# Pandas: replacing similar values with a derived values

Tags: pandas

How do I group proximate values (within some threshold) and replace them with an aggregate (e.g. mean, max, etc.).  For example, consider the following data:

```
cat1 cat2  value       new_value
A     a   1523314515  1523314515
A     b   1523318114  1523318114
A     c   1523318115  1523318114
B     a   1523314604  1523314603
B     b   1523314605  1523314603
B     c   1523314603  1523314603
B     d   1523331024  1523331024
C     a   1523313948  1523313948
C     b   1523314790  1523314790
D     a   1523313952  1523313952
D     b   1523314815  1523314815
E     a   1523529294  1523529292
E     b   1523529295  1523529292
E     c   1523529292  1523529292
E     d   1523529297  1523529292
```

within a group defined by `cat1`, if the values fall within the range of 10, the new value should be the min value of that cluster.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, here's a solution using `np.where`. Row 2 comes out differently from your expected output, so I think I'm not capturing your description exactly -- or `df.loc[2, 'new_value']` should be `1523318115` instead of `1523318114`.

```
cat2min = df.groupby('cat1')['value'].min()
mins = df['cat1'].map(cat2min)
df['new_value_calc'] = np.where(np.abs(df['value'] - mins) <= 10,
                                mins, 
                                df['value'])
df
   cat1 cat2       value   new_value  new_value_calc
0     A    a  1523314515  1523314515      1523314515
1     A    b  1523318114  1523318114      1523318114
2     A    c  1523318115  1523318114      1523318115
3     B    a  1523314604  1523314603      1523314603
4     B    b  1523314605  1523314603      1523314603
5     B    c  1523314603  1523314603      1523314603
6     B    d  1523331024  1523331024      1523331024
7     C    a  1523313948  1523313948      1523313948
8     C    b  1523314790  1523314790      1523314790
9     D    a  1523313952  1523313952      1523313952
10    D    b  1523314815  1523314815      1523314815
11    E    a  1523529294  1523529292      1523529292
12    E    b  1523529295  1523529292      1523529292
13    E    c  1523529292  1523529292      1523529292
14    E    d  1523529297  1523529292      1523529292
```

Comment: Yes, I think I was a bit imprecise in my description.  To simplify: I want to cluster rows into groups where for every such group  `max(value)-min(value) < 10`.  There could be multiple of these clusters per `cat1`, but a cluster cannot span multiple `cat1`s.  Then for every such formed cluster `new_value = average(value)`